# C write uint16 to file got Error

Tags: c, fwrite, uint16

My operation-system is window,I want to write my data to a pcm with 16bit.Here is my code:

```
typedef unsigned short uint16;
void write2PCM(char* file_path, int length, double* data) {
FILE* file=NULL;
file = fopen(file_path, "wb+");
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    uint16 val=data[i]*10000;
    uint16 fin_val = (val >> 8 & 0x00ff) | (val << 8 & 0xff00);
    fwrite(fin_val,sizeof(fin_val),1,file);
}

fclose;}
```

and when I invoke it,I got Error in the place  of  fwrite:
"An access violation occurred while reading location 0x....",
 I can see the file has been created successfully,so I don't konw why this Error occured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you really get any diagnostics *at all*? Every single warning from C compiler is **significant**, they're usually signs of grave errors! Also, when you do ask on Stack Overflow, please copy any diagnostics from the compiler verbatim into the question.

The problem is here:

```
fwrite(fin_val, sizeof(fin_val), 1, file);
```

The prototype of `fwrite` is

```
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

The first argument **must** be a pointer to const void, yet you pass in a `uint16_t`. It should be `&fin_val`,  so that `fwrite` gets the address to that variable.

On a related note, `fclose;` is not a function call, and this too should have produced a diagnostic message in any sane compiler. It should be `fclose(file);`.

Here's an example output from GCC without warnings:

```
% gcc -c pcm.c
pcm.c: In function ‘write2PCM’:
pcm.c:10:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fwrite’ makes pointer from integer without a 
             cast [-Wint-conversion]
     fwrite(fin_val,sizeof(fin_val),1,file);
            ^~~~~~~
```

and here with all warnings enabled:

```
% gcc -c pcm.c -Wall
pcm.c: In function ‘write2PCM’:
pcm.c:10:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fwrite’ makes pointer from integer without a 
             cast [-Wint-conversion]
     fwrite(fin_val,sizeof(fin_val),1,file);
            ^~~~~~~
In file included from pcm.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:717:15: note: expected ‘const void * restrict’ but argument is of 
             type ‘uint16 {aka short unsigned int}’
 extern size_t fwrite (const void *__restrict __ptr, size_t __size,
               ^~~~~~
pcm.c:13:1: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
 fclose;}
 ^~~~~~
```

Comment: I use vs2017,There is just a error message:An access violation occurred while reading location 0x.... ,no warining like gcc@_@!

Comment: @马慧超 during the *compilation*, not during running the program.

Comment: @马慧超 it is absolutely necessary for you to find where these compiler diagnostics are output and read them carefully, otherwise you'll never program a working C program! :D

Comment: thanks for your advice,I will improve myself and check the error carefully next time,Thanks guy,very appreaciate.

Answer (score 0):

`fwrite` expects a pointer to the data you want to write.

This will write `fin_val` to the file in binary mode:

```
fwrite(&fin_val,sizeof(fin_val),1,file);
```

Your compiler should have warned you that you provided an integer value instead of a pointer. You should turn up the warning level of your compiler. If you use `gcc`, add `-Wall` to the compiler command line.

Comment: thanks ,I am not very familiar with c,now I know what's the problem,thanks very much.

Comment: The important thing is that you turn on/up compiler warnings. It will help you a lot in the future. The compiler can find many (but far from all) coding mistakes.

Comment: I will remember that and improve myself,but there is a little error message in vs but a lot in gcc..

Comment: @马慧超 In Visual Studio I suggest you use /W4 for new code. See https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level

Comment: that's a good idea ,I will try that,thanks ,You are very enthusiastic.